# Selecting a "correct" solution to a quadratic congruence

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am investigating how the least residue of $\frac{p-1}{2}!\pmod{p}$ is congruent to one of the solutions of $x^{2} \equiv -1 \ \pmod{p}$ for $4k+1$ primes. I want to find out if there is a way to determine which one of the two solutions of the quadratic solution is congruent to the least residue of $\frac{p-1}{2}!\pmod{p}$ for any $p = 4k+1$. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to know if $\frac{p-1}{2}!$ is congruent to an element of $\{1,2,\dotsc,\frac{p-1}{2}\}$ modulo $p$?

Comment: Similar question for $p\equiv 3\mod 4$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-2-1-mod-p

Comment: Even more similar to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28958