# Jacobi symbols for two-square sums of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

Given a prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, Fermat's two-squares theorem discovered by Girard
states that there exists two integers $A,B$ such that
$p=A^2+B^2$.

For all primes up to $10^7$ the integers $A$ and $B$ are squares modulo $p$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$ and they are fourth powers modulo $p$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod {16}$. This pattern breaks then down: $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily $8$-th powers modulo $p$ for primes $p\equiv 1\pmod{32}$.

*Is there an explanation (proof or reference)
for these observations? Is there an explanation why they fail to
carry on?*

**Details:** We start with $p=A^2+B^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.
Since we have obviously $(A/B)^2\equiv -1\pmod p$ this implies
that
$\left(\frac{AB}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(p-1)/4}$ with $\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)$
denoting the Jacobi-symbol (which equals $1$ on non-zero squares and $-1$
on non-squares in $\mathbb F_p$).

This shows that $\left(\frac{A}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{B}{p}\right)$
if $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$. Surprisingly, negative Jacobi-symbols do not occur for
small primes and we have $\left(\frac{A}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{B}{p}\right)=1$ for all 165976 primes $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$ up to $10^7$.

Given a prime $p=A^2+B^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$
with $\left(\frac{A}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{B}{p}\right)=1$ we can
choose square roots $a,b$ of $A\equiv a^2\pmod p$ and $B\equiv b^2\pmod p$.
We have then $(ab^{-1})^4\equiv -1\pmod p$ which shows $\left(
  \frac{ab}{p}\right)\equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/8}$ and we get
therefore $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{b}{p}\right)$
if $p\equiv 1\pmod{16}$. (The choice of initial signs for $A,B$ and
the choice between the two possible square-roots for $a$ or $b$
do not change the values of the Jacobi-symbols.)

We get again
$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{b}{p}\right)=1$ for all
82967 primes $p\equiv 1\pmod{16}$ up to $10^7$ and we can
then choose square roots $\alpha,\beta$ of $a\equiv \alpha^2\pmod{p}$
and $b\equiv \beta^2\pmod{p}$ (or, equivalently, fourth-roots of
$A\equiv \alpha^4\pmod p$ and $B\equiv \beta^4\pmod p$ where
$p=A^2+B^2\equiv 1\pmod{16}$). We have again
$\left(\frac{\alpha\beta}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(p-1)/16}$.

We have therefore $\left(\frac{\alpha}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{\beta}{p}\right)$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod{32}$.

The pattern observed experimentally above breaks down at this point.
We have for example

$193=7^2+12^2$ with $83^4\equiv 7\pmod{193},\ 75^4\equiv 12\pmod{193}$ and $\left(\frac{83}{193}\right)=\left(\frac{75}{193}\right)=1$,

$673=12^2+23^2$ with $194^4\equiv 12\pmod{673},\ 206^4\equiv 23\pmod{673}$ and $\left(\frac{194}{673}\right)=\left(\frac{206}{673}\right)=1$

but we have

$97=4^2+9^2$ with $14^4\equiv 4\pmod{97},\ 10^4\equiv 9\pmod{97}$ and
$\left(\frac{14}{97}\right)=\left(\frac{10}{97}\right)=-1$,

$1153=8^2+33^2$ with $425^4\equiv 8\pmod{1153},\ 269^4\equiv 33\pmod{1153}$
and $\left(\frac{425}{1153}\right)=\left(\frac{269}{1153}\right)=-1$.

(More precisely, there are 41453 primes congruent to $1\pmod {32}$ up to $10^7$. These primes yield 20613 times $\left(\frac{\alpha}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{\beta}{p}\right)=1$. Both Jacobi-symbols are equal to $-1$ for
the remaining 20840 primes congruent to $1\pmod{32}$ up to $10^7$.)

Comment: The post is long. Could you summarize the observations as its own focused paragraph: what appears to happen when $p\equiv 1 \bmod 8$, then $p\equiv 1\bmod 16$, and then say what breaks for modulus 32? That way a reader can see the main point more efficiently.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks, good point. It is hopefully better now.

Comment: There are explicit formulas for $A$ and $B$. If $p=4k+1$, we can take $A$ to be the absolute least residue of $(2k)!/(2(k!)^2)\bmod p$, and $B$ the absolute least residue of $A(2k)!$. Maybe this helps. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45155

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good point. Based on this result and another result of Emma Lehmer (1977), I managed to prove that $A$ and $B$ are fourth powers modulo $p$ when $p\equiv 1\pmod{16}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added another proof (called "First proof" in my post) that proceeds differently. This proof actually shows that if $p=A^2+B^2$ is a prime with $B\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, then every odd prime divisor of $B$ is a fourth power modulo $p$, and the $2$-power part of $B$ is also a fourth power modulo $p$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added a third proof (called "Second proof" in my post) based on quartic reciprocity in Gaussian integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first observation follows from the law of quadratic reciprocity. Indeed, assume that $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ and $p=A^2+B^2$. Let $A'$ denote the odd part of $A$. Then $p\equiv B^2\pmod{A'}$, and hence $\left(\frac{p}{A'}\right)=1$. It follows that $\left(\frac{A'}{p}\right)=1$, and then by $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$ also $\left(\frac{A}{p}\right)=1$. In the same way, $\left(\frac{B}{p}\right)=1$. The second observation lies deeper. I will give three proofs (which actually yield more than we need).

**First proof.** I will use some results of Gauss, Jacobi, and Eisenstein collected in Section III.13.5 of Hasse's 1965 book: Bericht über neuere Untersuchungen und Probleme aus der Theorie der algebraischen Zahlkörper, Teil II: Reziprozitätsgesetz. Assume that $p\equiv 1\pmod{16}$. Without loss of generality, $A$ is odd and $B$ is even. As $A/B$ is a square-root of $-1$ modulo $p$, it has order four modulo $p$, hence it is actually a fourth power modulo $p$. Therefore, it suffices to show that $B$ is a fourth power modulo $p$. Let us write $B=2^k B'$, where $k\geq 2$ and $B'$ is odd. By the results in Hasse's book, every prime divisor of $B'$ is a fourth power modulo $p$, hence $B'$ is a fourth power modulo $p$. It remains to show that $2^k$ is a fourth power modulo $p$. If $k\geq 3$, then $2$ is a fourth power modulo $p$ (see Hasse's book), hence we are done. If $k=2$, then we are also done upon noting that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

**Second proof.** This proof is based on the properties of the quartic residue symbol in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I will rely on Chapter 9 of Ireland-Rosen: A classical introduction to modern number theory (2nd ed.), especially Theorem 2, Proposition 9.8.5, and Proposition 9.8.6 there. Assume that $p\equiv 1\pmod{16}$. There are $8$ pairs representing $p$, hence we can assume that our pair $(A,B)$ is the one with
$$A\equiv 1\pmod{8}\qquad\text{and}\qquad B\equiv 0\pmod{4}.$$
As $A/B$ is a square-root of $-1$ modulo $p$, it has order four modulo $p$, hence it is actually a fourth power modulo $p$. Therefore, it suffices to show that $A$ is a fourth power modulo $p$. Equivalently, $A$ is a fourth power in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(A+Bi)$. However, this follows from the law of quartic reciprocity and the conditions on $(A,B)$:
$$\left(\frac{A}{A+Bi}\right)_4=\left(\frac{A+Bi}{A}\right)_4
=\left(\frac{Bi}{A}\right)_4=\left(\frac{i}{A}\right)_4=(-1)^{(A-1)/4}=1.$$

**Third proof.** I will use Gerry Myerson's helpful comment below the original post. For any prime $p=4n+1$, Gauss (1825) observed that $p=A^2+B^2$, where $A$ and $B$ are the absolute least residues modulo $p$ of $(2n)!/(2n!^2)$ and $(2n)!^2/(2n!^2)$. For a proof, see [Jacobsthal (1907)](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/download/pdf/PPN243919689_0132/LOG_0017.pdf) or the "Added" section below. Hence it suffices to show that in case when $4$ divides $n$, these two integers are fourth powers modulo $p$. So let us assume that $4\mid n$. By Wilson's theorem,
$$(2n)!^{(p-1)/4}=(2n)!^{n}\equiv(p-1)!^{n/2}\equiv(-1)^{n/2}=1\pmod{p},$$
hence $(2n)!$ is a fourth power modulo $p$. So we only need to prove that $2n!^2$ is a fourth power modulo $p$. Equivalently,
$$2^{(p-1)/4}n!^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}.\tag{1}$$
However, this follows from Theorem 5 in Emma Lehmer's 1977 paper "Generalizations of Gauss's lemma", and we are done.

For completeness, I spell out the proof of $(1)$. We observe that $n!^{(p-1)/2}\equiv(-1)^\nu\pmod{p}$, where $\nu$ is the number of quadratic non-residues in $[1,n]$. Hence $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$2^n(-1)^\nu\equiv 1\pmod{p}.\tag{2}$$
To see this, let $a_1,\dotsc,a_\nu$ be the quadratic non-residues in $[1,n]$, and let $a_{\nu+1},\dotsc,a_n$ be the quadratic non-residues in $[n+1,2n]$. Then $2a_1,\dotsc,2a_\nu$ are the even quadratic non-residues in $[2,2n]$, and $p-2a_{\nu+1},\dotsc,p-2a_n$ are the odd quadratic non-residues in $[1,2n-1]$. It follows that
$$\prod_{j=1}^\nu(2a_j)\prod_{j=\nu+1}^n(p-2a_j)=\prod_{j=1}^n a_j.$$
Taking residues modulo $p$ on both sides, we obtain after simplification that
$$2^\nu(-2)^{n-\nu}\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$$
This is equivalent to $(2)$, because $n$ is even.

**Added.** To make this post more self-contained, I provide a proof of Gauss's observation $p=A^2+B^2$, using Jacobi sums. Here $A$ and $B$ are the absolute least residues modulo $p$ of $(2n)!/(2n!^2)$ and $(2n)!^2/(2n!^2)$. I will rely on Chapter 8 of Ireland-Rosen: A classical introduction to modern number theory (2nd ed.), especially Theorem 1, Theorem 5, and Exercise 26 there.

Let $\chi$ be a character of order four on $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$, and let $\rho$ be the Legendre symbol on $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$. The number of solutions of $x^4+y^2=1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ can be expressed via Jacobi sums as
\begin{align*}
N&=p+J(\chi,\rho)+J(\chi^2,\rho)+J(\chi^3,\rho)\\
&=p+J(\chi,\rho)+J(\rho,\rho)+\overline{J(\chi,\rho)}\\
&=p-1+2a,
\end{align*}
where $J(\chi,\rho)=a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Note that
$$p=|J(\chi,\rho)|^2=a^2+b^2.\tag{3}$$
The count $N$ can also be evaluated as
$$N=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(1+\rho(1-x^4))=p+\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\rho(1-x^4).$$
Now we determine $a\bmod p$ using the two expressions for $N$. Recalling that $n=(p-1)/4$,
$$2a-1=\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\rho(1-x^4)\equiv\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(1-x^4)^{2n}\pmod{p}.$$
We expand $(1-x^4)^{2n}$ by the binomial theorem:
$$2a-1\equiv\sum_{m=0}^{2n}(-1)^m\binom{2n}{m}\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}x^{4m}\pmod{p}.$$
The inner sum on the right-hand side is $-1\bmod p$ when $m\in\{n,2n\}$, and $0\bmod p$ otherwise. As a result,
$$2a\equiv(-1)^{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\pmod{p}.$$
From here it is straightforward that $|a|=|A|$ and $|b|=|B|$, hence $p=A^2+B^2$ by $(3)$.

Comment: Nice observation which shows a bit more: The odd number among $\lbrace A,B\rbrace$ is always a square modulo $p$. If $p\equiv 5\pmod 8$, then half of the even number (which is odd) is therefore also a square.

Comment: The proof by Barnes is fatally flawed if my memory is correct.

Comment: @RolandBacher I don't know that. The brief MathSciNet review about Barnes' paper was written by Paul Erdős, but that of course does not mean much. Jacobsthal's proof should be reliable (and there was an earlier proof by Cauchy, presumably hard to read for us). BTW, I expect that one can also see from the analysis for $p\equiv 1\pmod{16}$ why the pattern breaks down for $p\equiv 1\pmod{32}$. Thanks for accepting my answer officially!

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! (Concerning the Barnes proof : I remember having read it 30 years ago and there was a really stupid mistake with modular arithmetics (the type of mistake in all those marvellous proofs of the Fermat-Wiles Theorem).)

Comment: @RolandBacher I removed the reference to Barnes (1974), but added a detailed treatment in the "Added" section. I found the exposition in Jacobsthal (1907) too terse.

Comment: @GHfromMO I've added my reconstruction of Jacobsthal's argument as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer but a comment to GH from MO's answer.

As I understand, Jacobstahl proved Gauss's congruences in a more direct way. He didn't use Jacobi sums. In Jacobstahl's representation $p=A^2+B^2$ numbers $A$ and $B$ are expressed in terms of sums of Legendre symbols:
$$2A=\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^3+rx}p\right),\quad 2B=\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{x^3+nx}p\right),$$
where $r$ and $n$ are quadratic residue and non-residue modulo $p$. From these representations desired congruences follow directly. For $r=1$
$$\begin{split}2A\equiv\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\left({x^3+x}\right)^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left({g^{3k}+g^k}\right)^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv\sum_{j=0}^{(p-1)/2}\binom{(p-1)/2}{j}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(g^{3k})^{j}(g^k)^{\frac{p-1}{2}-j}\\\equiv\sum_{j=0}^{(p-1)/2}\binom{(p-1)/2}{j}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}g^{k\left(2j+\frac{p-1}{2}\right)}\pmod p.\end{split}$$
The inner sum is not zero modulo $p$ iff $2j+\frac{p-1}2=p-1,$ or $j=\frac{p-1}4$. So $2A\equiv \binom{(p-1)/2}{(p-1)/4}.$ Also we know that $(A/B)^2\equiv -1\pmod p$, hence $B\equiv \pm (\frac{p-1}2)!A.$